# Identifying Smaller Tree

Tags: identification, watering, tree-care

Can anyone help me identify this tree **and tell me exactly how much water I need to give it?**

I leave it out under direct sunlight, as it was when I bought it. *(Shop staff had absolutely no idea what species it was or how much water. Was not a plant shop)*

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you break a leaf does a white sap come out?

Comment: @kevinsky no white sap, just clear fluid

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing a bit more about the plant. Over the course of a year or so it should be fairly obvious. Some things that come to mind when looking at your photo's:

Some type of Laurel, Bull Bay, or this may be a very young octopus tree. These things are hard to tell.

In general, water it once a day and monitor it closely. Follow that pattern for a week or so and prune. If the tree reacts properly and creates new growth then your fine to continue with that watering pattern. If the tree does not create new growth attempt to add some nutrients to your water and try again.

Also, take a look on-line. There are many different plant identification apps which you can download from the app store.

Comment: Thanks so much. Never heard of a plant ID app before. Awesome